# I want to pass Screen_Name as an attribute in a class model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, function, class, navigation, arguments

Actually I have a card that have a title and image and navigate to specific route. I want to pass screen name as an attribute in class model. but when i clicked nothing happen and this message appear in console:

> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 4135 pos 12: 'name != null': is not true.

This is The Class Model:

```
class ZekrModel {
  final String zekrTitle;
  final String zekrImage;
  final String zekrPage;
  ZekrModel({this.zekrTitle, this.zekrImage, this.zekrPage});
}
```

This is The Provider:

```
class ZekrProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  List<ZekrModel> _zekrList = [
    ZekrModel(
        zekrTitle: 'أذكار المساء',
        zekrImage: 'assets/images/az6.png',
        zekrPage: 'AlsabahScreen.id',
      ),
  ];

  List<ZekrModel> get zekrList {
    return _zekrList;
  }
}
```

Here is The UI Code which exactly code doesn't response:

```
Consumer<ZekrProvider>(
        builder:(context, value, child) => GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.3.sw/0.18.sh,
          //mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          //crossAxisSpacing: 6,
          children: List.generate(value.zekrList.length, (index){
            return ZekrCard(
              zekrTitle: value.zekrList[index].zekrTitle,
              zekrImage: value.zekrList[index].zekrImage,
              zekrRoute: (){Navigator.pushNamed(context, value.zekrList[index].zekrPage);},
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
```

Here is my routes class:

```
final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = {
  SplashScreen.routeName : (context) => SplashScreen(),
  AlsabahScreen.routeName : (context) => AlsabahScreen(),
};
```

Comment: what is the proplem?

Comment: It doesn't response and when i clicked on it this message appear in console:

Comment: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4135 pos 12: 'name != null': is not true.

Comment: please share MaterialApp routes

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I solved it using this steps:

First: Add this attr to model class

```
final MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute;
```

To be Like This:

```
class ZekrModel {
  final String zekrTitle;
  final String zekrImage;
  final MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute;

  ZekrModel({this.zekrTitle, this.zekrImage, this.materialPageRoute});

}
```

Second: use this attr in Provider class

```
materialPageRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen())
```

To Be like this:

```
class ZekrProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  List<ZekrModel> _zekrList = [
    ZekrModel(
        zekrTitle: 'أذكار المساء',
        zekrImage: 'assets/images/az6.png',
        materialPageRoute: MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlmasaaScreen())
    ),
];

  List<ZekrModel> get zekrList {
    return _zekrList;
  }
}
```

Last use it in UI:

```
body: Consumer<ZekrProvider>(
        builder:(context, value, child) => GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.3.sw/0.18.sh,
          //mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          //crossAxisSpacing: 6,
          children: List.generate(value.zekrList.length, (index){
            return ZekrCard(
              zekrTitle: value.zekrList[index].zekrTitle,
              zekrImage: value.zekrList[index].zekrImage,
              zekrRoute: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context, value.zekrList[index].materialPageRoute
              );
            },
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
```